# Build an executable using a pattern in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is a simple `Makefile` content:

```
CXXCOMP=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -g

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXXCOMP) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

main: %.o
    $(CXXCOMP) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

I expect that the first rule will generate a `.o` file for each `.cpp` one, while the second rule will generate a `main` file from all the `.o` ones.

Actually, the following statement is printed to terminal when I try to make `main`:

```
target `main' doesn't match the target pattern
```

Can you please explain a bit more in depth what's going on and how to solve this little issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%.o` is not a shell wildcard, it works only in the context of *pattern rules*. To do what you want you have to use the [*wildcard* function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Examples), e.g.

```
 main: $(wildcard *.o)
           $(CXXCOMP) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

but as Matt correctly points out, has a set of different problems. A better way is to use a *make* variable for the source files, and then construct the list of object files.

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

main: $(OBJ)
      ...
```

Comment: ... or name all the sources or objects explicitly, which is safer and more traditional, and can even afford a makefile that doesn't rely on GNU extensions..

Comment: Is `wildcard` a bash command or is it a GNU make only function? I am asking this because `make` prints a `clang` error, now: `no input files`. Using other words, should I install something more in order to use `wildcard`?

Answer (score 2):

As John Bollinger pointed out in the comments, you should probably name either the sources or the object files explicitly. Not doing so is less safe, less predictable, and the price you pay in makefile complexity isn't even worth it.

To circumvent the complexity, you would have to have all of your header files, source files, object files, and output files in the same folder, which isn't great. This would, however, allow you to simply use the `$(wildcard *.cpp)` function. Otherwise you would have to chain a series of calls to first get all of the source files in the `src` directory, use the `notdir` function to strip the directory part of the name, and then use the `patsubst` function to do a switcheroo on the filename extension. That would look something like this:

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(notdir $(wildcard src/*.cpp)))
```

I personally prefer listing all the object files explicitly, but this will do what you want.

As an aside, the reason you need the `wildcard` function specifically is because while wildcards will generally work as expected in rules and targets, you're using it in a variable assignment, where it is being taken literally. If you set `OBJS` to `*.o` and echo the variable, you get this:

```
OBJS = *.o

echo_objs:
    @echo $(OBS)
```

Output:

```
echo *.o
```

Running the whole makefile gives the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '*.o', needed by 'project'.  Stop.
```

There are no object files in the directory currently, so using the wildcard function in the assignment results in echoing out nothing, which is the usual behavior. I echoed the names of all the object files in the directory: none.

What I like to do is list the object files like this:

```
OBJS = main.o file.o string.o # or whatever
```

Then, having previously set the `vpath` variable like this:

```
vpath %.cpp src
vpath %.hpp include
```

I can simply write:

```
OBJS = main.o
ASMS = $(patsubst %.o, %.asm, $(OBJS))

TARGET = project_name

all: assembler_output $(TARGET) # etc

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -I include    -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -I include -c -o $@ $^

assembler_output: $(ASMS)

%.asm: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -I include -masm=intel -S -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I included the additional target, because a) I like seeing what the compiler (and occasionally the preprocessor) are doing before the linker is invoked, and b) hopefully it helps modularize your goals somewhat.

---

Having hopefully answered the main question, I do have some suggestions on your makefile. You should really stick to the convention of naming the C compiler variable `CC` and the C++ compiler `CXX`, especially if you want to publish your code for others to use. Your users will expect to be able to configure the compilation settings for the project when they build it (maybe they don't have or use g++), and they'll be in for a surprise when they keep changing the `CXX` variable to no avail.

While a makefile for a toy project is short, they can get pretty unwieldy pretty fast, especially with test code, installation directives, etc., so making your users have to `cat -n ./makefile | grep -E 'CXX'` for all possible compilation directives to hunt down the actual variable will be pretty annoying. Not to mention you're declaring the variable *in* the makefile, so they can't override the settings. You might want to use `?=` for those variables, that way they're only defined if no settings have been set through the console.

In fact, if you run `make --print-data-base` in the project directory and `grep -E 'COMPILE'`, you can see the exact commands `make` has built-in to compile C, C++, assembler, fortran, etc. For C++ the command is:

```
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

Since your users can configure those flags though, make sure your mandatory `include` directories aren't in `CPPFLAGS`. That variable is for optional libraries' include directories, in case your application allows users to compile with additional functionality if they have a specific library installed.

The linker command is `LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)`, where `LDFLAGS` is the linker variable your users will also expect to be able to configure.

---

All of this really starts to matter once your projects start gaining size and complexity. Large projects will usually have nested subfolders and a top-level makefile will call each nested makefile recursively, and this is when sticking to a clear, well-defined convention starts to really matter.

Writing good makefiles takes practice, but it can be super rewarding. I've seen some truly masterful ones, none of them written by me, unfortunately. Hopefully this helps somewhat, though; for me it always helps to know why things are done they way they are, from a technical standpoint, before I really understand and embrace accepted practices.

Comment: Considering the conventions that you mentioned, what is the difference between `$(CXXFLAGS)` and `$(CPPFLAGS)`?

Comment: `CXXFLAGS` is for C++ compilation-specific flags, while `CPPFLAGS` is specifically for preprocessor options (that's what the PP stands for, not 'C Plus Plus' as some might think). It's also used in C builds by default, which you can also see with `make --print-data-base | grep -E 'COMPILE'` under `COMPILE.c`

Comment: `If you set OBJS to *.o and echo the variable, you get this` Actually, this is a bad example, as any POSIX shell/echo **will** expand the wildcards automatically.

Comment: I made sure to test it beforehand (I'm on manjaro linux) and `make` echoed exactly `echo *.o`, but I will admit I'm not sure exactly why bash didn't interpret the wildcard as such